# Video on iPad has letter boxing but not on desktop

Tags: ios, html, css

I am trying to get the iPad video to display the same as the desktop. I am using media queries redirecting the browser to different stylesheets depending on the browser size. The video css is the same for both desktop and tablet.

On the desktop the user can view a full height and width video in the background, when resizing the browser the video adapts to the browser until the width is 640px then I have changed display: none for the video.

When browsing on the iPad however, the video has a 100& width but the height is not 100% leaving letter boxing. Any help with this.

Other sections or div tags with 100% height works fine. Any comments or help would be much appreciated, thank you (Y)

HTML Header:

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"> 

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="styles/index/mobile.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 480px)" href="styles/index/600px.css"/>   
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 600px)" href="styles/index/tablet.css" />   
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1024px)" href="styles/index/stylesheet.css"/>
```

Video CSS for desktop and tablet:

```
#video_background { 
display:block;  
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0px; 
right: 0px; 
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%; 
z-index: -1000; 
overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an iPad near me, so I can't really test. But I've seen issues like this before (regarding situations where folks need 100% heights).

This would be my best guess:

Add top: 0px; to your #video_background CSS, probably wouldn't hurt to add left: 0px; as well. Essentially, doing this:

```
#video_background { 
display:block;  
position: absolute; 
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px; 
right: 0px; 
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%; 
z-index: -1000; 
overflow: hidden; }
```

Again, I don't have an iPad with me to test.

Hope this helps!

Good luck